# C: cannot create or append to a file

Tags: c, file

I am trying to open a file for both read and write operations.
If the file is already there, it should append. (I want to be able to write to it, and maybe read from it later)

However, if the file is there, I cannot append to it (I get a permission denied: cannot create file)

```
int main()
{
       int file;
       file = open("redirect.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 777);
       if(!(file == -1)) //edited per comment
       {
            close(file);
       }
      else
           perror("File could not be created\n");

     return 0;
}
```

This only opens a new file if it does not exist, but does not append to an existing file if it does exist.

Comment: If you get the message "cannot create file" that implies it does not already exist, after all.

Comment: The file does exist in that directory, and I can open it (and see it in ls).

Comment: We need to see the output of `id` and `ls -l redirect.txt`.  Also, `777` should be `0777`, but that is not your immediate problem.

Comment: Also also, that `perror` message will (and indeed _has_) confuse people.  I recommend `perror("redirect.txt")` instead.

Comment: `open` can return `0` for success but is denied by your calling code.

Comment: Sorry, what is         id ? The file variable is -1 when the file is already there. I think O_APPEND does not work, and it cannot create a new file because one already exists? 
The problem is the file id is always -1, so my perror if is not the issue right now (I checked in gdb)

Comment: `id` is a command you can type into a terminal, as is `ls -l redirect.txt`.  Please type those two commands into your terminal and then copy and paste the output, __unedited__, into the question.

Comment: The result of `ls -l redirect.txt` is `-r----x--x  1 name  staff  0  1 Oct 20:02 redirect.txt`

Comment: Doh, of course. DimeCadmium's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting that the mode parameter to `open()` must be in octal. This will work:

```
file = open("redirect.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0777);
```

As zwol also mentioned, it's generally a good idea to create files with 0666 (since they don't need to be executable).

Comment: (since I can't comment on the parent) @zwol, it is indeed his problem. 777 (non-octal) results in `1411/-r----x--t` = sticky + u+r,go+x)

Comment: You're quite right, but it needs a bit more explanation: specifying the mode in decimal caused the file to be created with permission bits that forbade the subsequent attempt to reopen the file for writing.  OP will need to `chmod` the file or delete and recreate it before the program will start working as intended.

Comment: It would also maybe be good to recommend the use of 0666 instead of 0777.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Thanks!